# TFS 2012 - Code review - Reviewer name is not in the list of allowed reviewers

Tags: tfs, tfs-code-review

I want to use TFS 2012 code review template. I am using vS2012 online TFS workspace, where i created 5 of users.
From VS2012 I am trying to Add Reviewer to review my code, it display error like "Reviewer name  is not in the list of allowed reviewers."

Comment: Why to downgrade? let reason should know.

Comment: Does the reviewer name match exactly with one of the TFS users? What happens if you use the admin user's name? Is there a reviewer permission or group that you need to apply? 

In short, what have you done to try and resolve the problem?

Comment: Thanks, penguat. I found the way, I was not aware about TFS settings. By default all users are created as normal users. Now i found we can make user as administrator. Now its works fine, thanks.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you answer the question, sharing details about how you solved it? That way, the next person hopefully won't have the same trouble.

Comment: I am new to TFS management, So not aware about settings. Here is my Answer how to resolve.
-- when user open TFS link, its open in Overview mode.
In Right side pane, there are options like ACTIVITIES, MEMBERS, ADMINISTRATION.
This ADMINISTRATION link is for Sprint management, not user Management.
To do user management, Click on Top Right Setting symbol [Next to Help link]
Here you go, select Project and select your team
Left side panel, User can add multiple Administrators.
Now try to add the same name / email id in Reviewer name.
No error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to go to your Team Project and add some users to your Team. If you first select your Team Project \ Team you will notice that you have a "Members (0)" on the right. If you click "Manage all members" under that heading you can add any number of Windows or Microsoft Id users to that list.

[image: Adding Users to a Team]

Now that you have the users added to the Team, if you also select that Team in Visual Studio you will be able to select any of those users for review. This list is in fact of all users that have 'contributor' permissions to the Team Project which is granted by using the above process.

If you are having trouble setting up and configuring teams I have created a post on [Modelling Teams in Team Foundation Server 2013](http://nakedalm.com/modelling-teams-in-team-foundation-server-2013/).

Comment: Thanks MrHinsh, I was not aware about User Permissions.

Answer (score 0):

After several weeks with that problem, I found out that I had to do a hard clear cache on my Visual Studio. After that, it showed me a correct list of reviewers.

I found out that by this forum post: https://developercommunityapi.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/content/problem/1145784/reviewer-name-is-not-in-the-list-of-allowed-review-1.html

And here is how you can clear the cache of VS (I had to do all steps):
https://errorhandlinginskills.wordpress.com/2018/07/28/how-to-clear-visual-studio-cache/

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with VS 2019. I tried to Add Reviewer to review my code, it displayed the error:

> Reviewer name is not in the list of allowed reviewers.

**Note:** It worked perfectly for most users in Azure Dev Ops, just one or two newly added users (which were in the Contributors group) were giving the error above.

The following steps fixed it for me:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio,
2. Delete `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\8.0\Cache`,
3. Restart VS.